# Be there, for the square

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Sometimes when you're lying in bed and reading a message, your phone screen will pop into landscape mode right in the middle of a sentence. Only being able to read left to right, you find yourself incapacitated, unable to process the text in front of you.

To ensure that this won't happen again, you decide to make every message readable from any angle, whether your phone screen is rotated or mirrored. To make this happen, each message is printed as a square, with each side of the square containing the message, either in the original order or in reverse.

- For backwards compatibility, the top side of the square should be the original message.
- To make each message square as compact as possible, the first and last character of the message should be a part of two sides of the square. This means that the top side reads normally, the bottom side is in reverse, the left side reads top-bottom, and the right side reads bottom-top.

### Input

A single string, with 2 or more characters. You should not assume that the string only contains alphanumerical characters or similar.

### Output

The Squarification™ of the string. It is permissible to leave some whitespace at the end of each line, and a single newline at the end of the output.

### Examples

```
Input: 'ab'
ab
ba

Input: 'abc'

abc
b b
cba

Input: 'Hello, world!'
Hello, world!
e           d
l           l
l           r
o           o
,           w

w           ,
o           o
r           l
l           l
d           e
!dlrow ,olleH
```

This challenge looks like [A cube of text](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92410/a-cube-of-text-%DD%80), but I'm hoping that it's different enough that there will be some clever answers.

As this is code-golf, get ready to trim some bytes!

Comment: Can the horizontal lines contain spaces between letters, as long as they align with margins? Example: the first line of output for `abc` would be `a b c`. Alternatively, can we output a list of lines? Nice challenge, btw

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder You may not have spaces in the middle of a line, so `abc` is always `abc`. EDIT: outputting a list of lines is allowed, just make sure that you have the joining in the footer so that answers can be verified easily.

Comment: Can we return a list of lines?

Comment: @JoKing Yes, a list of lines is allowed.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47710/52210)

Comment: "To ensure that this won't happen again, you decide to make every message readable from any angle, whether your phone screen is rotated or mirrored." - Or you could just, you know, enable the orientation lock for your phone...

Comment: @ArnavBorborah That sounds very hard, what if you forget to enable it in a moment where your immediate response is required?

Comment: "To ensure that this **won't happen again,**". You do it once, and then keep it on for as long as you choose. ;)

Comment: @maxb Is it ok if I take the input as an array of chars?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I'm not sure what the consensus is on that. I've looked into some meta posts, and from what I've seen it seems like `char[]` should be treated as a string. That would imply that taking input as a list of chars is allowed. However, please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Or you just add "rotate off" to your shortcuts that appear when you slide your finger from the top. ;-)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer but in a state of great confusion, how will I know which side of the phone is the top? I'd much rather use a few bytes of my phone's memory to save myself from the embarrassment of a late reply.

Comment: @maxb You are allowed to decide on your own question whether an array of chars is okay or not, along with any other input formats (base64 encoded string, sum of the squares of the factors of the Unicode values modulo 42, etc)

Comment: @Quintec I'll only allow modulo 43, get out of here with that non-prime modulo! Seriously though, thanks for the info, it'll help me with future challenges.

Comment: I suddenly have an urge to write an answer that takes input in that format

Answer (score 18):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 4 bytes

```
Ｓ‖Ｏ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMzr6C0JLgEyE7X0NS05gpKTctJTS7xL0stykks0LCK07T@/98jNScnX0chPL8oJ0WR679uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｓ       Input the string and implicitly print it
 ‖      Reflect...
  Ｏ     ... overlapping the first and last character...
   ^    ... in the ↙↘ directions (^ is shorthand for ↙↘).
```

Comment: I'm beyond impressed, nicely done!

Comment: This challenge is a perfect fit for charcoal :)

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

```
g4иsûûŽ9¦SΛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//2c00Lhzw7vDu8W9OcKmU86b//9IZWxsbywgd29ybGQh)

**Explanation**

```
g            # length of input
 4и          # quadruplicate in a list
             # these are the string lengths we'll print
   s         # push input
    ûû       # palendromize twice
             # this is the string we'll print
      Ž9¦S   # push [2,4,6,0]
             # these are the directions we'll print
          Λ  # paint on the canvas
```

Comment: This is just bizarre, very impressive!

Comment: @maxb: Will be interesting to see if Charcoal can do even shorter :)

Comment: Wouldn't Canvas also be suitable for something like this? I haven't coded anything in it myself, but from the other answers I've seen in Canvas it seems to be perfect for printing stuff

Comment: @maxb: It should be yes. I think this kind of challenge is pretty much what it was made for.

Comment: It is. In fact, I'm surprised that this question isn't a duplicate...

Comment: `gÐD)` can be `g4и`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Thanks! I didn't know that `и` had become a 1-byte command now :)

Comment: ... in fact it is a duplicate, see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133677/17602 where I only scored 5 with Charcoal yet still got the accepted answer!

Comment: @Neil: I knew I recognized it. I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>80</s> <s>76</s> <s>71</s> <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```python
lambda s:[s]+map((' '*len(s[2:])).join,zip(s,s[:0:-1]))[1:]+[s[::-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcqxDsIgEIDh3ac4pwOLxna8xN13QAZqS8RcgUAToy@PNC6O358/vddHDEN1l1tlu4yThUK6mG6xSQgEPPAcRNEDGSlPz@iD@vgkiiqaznTsW9U9mU43bzQ1ZR9WcALtiHL3p3ujixkYfNjKdWaOCl4x87RHSb@V6xc)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes

```python
lambda s:[s,*map((' '*len(s[2:])).join,zip(s[1:],s[-2:0:-1])),s[::-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYpBDsIgEEX3nmJcwTTU2LqbpHvvgCyobSNmCgSaGL080rhx9997P763R/CXsgy3wnYdJwuZdFbNaqOUAkTDs5dZ92QQT8/gvPq4WEVHRmXd9nSmtqutAu3LlJic3@QihR0F4uEP7zsvIQGD81DVdWYOCl4h8XQUSL8vY/kC)

Answer (score 7):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
⤢ｎ：±⇵ｎ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyOTIyJXVGRjRFJXVGRjFBJUIxJXUyMUY1JXVGRjRF,i=JTIySGVsbG8lMkMlMjBXb3JsZCUyMSUyMg__,v=8)

Explanation:

```
⤢       transpose the input
 n      and overlap that over the input
  :     duplicate that
   ±⇵   reverse it vertically & horizontally
     n  and overlap over the old version
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, <s>78</s> 76 Bytes

-2 bytes thanks to maxb!

```
lambda x:[x]+[x[i]+" "*(len(x)-2)+x[~i]for i in range(1,len(x)-1)]+[x[::-1]]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##LcuxCsIwEADQXzlvujOtEN0C7v6BQ5qh0kRP4qWEDnHx1yOI8@Ot7@1R9NTTeep5ft2WGZrzLRjfvASDgHvKUanxeGTT/EdCKhUERKHOeo9kh79b/i3nRhtCX6voBoST4uFZRCkRXmLOZYBrqXnZITP3Lw)

Comment: Outputting a list of lines is allowed! Also, `-i-1` can be written as `~i` to save two bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
¦¨s¨š.BsRøJIRª
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9vc2FiaWX//8KmwqhzwqjFoS5Cc1LDuErCuyxSPf//SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ)

Outputs as a list of lines, but the TIO link uses the old version which printed instead – [Try an alternative online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9vc2FiaWX//8KmwqhzwqjFoS5Cc1LDuEpJUsKqwrv//0hlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCE). Thought I'd be nice to show how awesome the canvas is by comparing that approach to others that don't use it. See Emigna's answer for a canvas version, then compare it to mine :)

#### How?

```
¦¨s¨š.BsRøJ»,R=    Full program. Accepts a string from STDIN. | Example: "abcd"
¦¨                 Tail and pop.                              | STACK: ["bc"]
  s¨               Swap and pop.                              | STACK: ["bc", "abc"]
    š              Prepend a to b as a list.                  | STACK: [["abc", "b", "c"]]
     .B            Squarify.                                  | STACK: [["abc", "b  ", "c  "]]
       sRøJ        Interleave with the reversed input.        | STACK: [["abcd", "b  c", "c  d"]].
           »,      Join by newlines, pop and print.           | STACK: [] (the above is removed after being printed)
             R=    Print the reversed input (taken implicitly due to the empty stack).
```

The only thing which is different in the 14-byter is that the reversed input is appended to the list rather than printed.

Comment: Not too far off Canvas. Nice!

Comment: What's the difference between `=` and `,`? I always (falsely) assumed `=` prints the last item of a list or something like that, but apparently it just prints the top of the stack with trailing newline, just like `,` does.. Is there a difference, or is it a duplicated 1-byte command we could use for something else?

Comment: @Kevin `,` pops, `=` doesn't. I have used them both while golfing, to be honest, so I guess each has its own purpose. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Ah ok. Personally I haven't used `=` yet, but I now understand the difference, thanks. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
YTO6Lt&(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzLE38ynRE3j/391j9ScnHwdhfL8opwURXUA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `'abcd'` as an example. Stack is shown bottom to top.

```
YT     % Implicit input: string. Create Toeplitz matrix of chars
       % STACK: ['abcd';
                 'babc';
                 'cbab';
                 'dcba']
O      % Push 0
       % STACK: ['abcd';
                 'babc';
                 'cbab';
                 'dcba']
                 0
6L     % Push [2, -1+1j]. Used as an index, this means 2:end
       % STACK: ['abcd';
                 'babc';
                 'cbab';
                 'dcba']
                 0,
                [2, -1+1j]
t      % Duplicate
       % STACK: ['abcd';
                 'babc';
                 'cbab';
                 'dcba']
                 0,
                [2, -1+1j],
                [2, -1+1j]
&(     % Write 0 into the internal entries of the char matrix.
       % STACK: ['abcd';
                 'b  c';
                 'c  b';
                 'dcba']
       % Implicitly display. Char 0 is shown as a space
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, <s>22</s> 15 bytes

```
U+ÕÅ+UÔÅ Õ·hJUw
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=VSvVxStV1MUg1bdoSlV3&input=IkhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCEiCgotUg==)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>55</s> 51 bytes

```perl6
{$_,|.comb[1..*-2].&{(@_ X~' 'x@_)Z~[R,] @_},.flip}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1olXqdGLzk/NynaUE9PS9coVk@tWsMhXiGiTl1BvcIhXjOqLjpIJ1bBIb5WRy8tJ7Og9n@ahlJikpKmnZ1ecWKlNReYm4zC90jNycnXUSjPL8pJUYTL/AcA)

Returns a list of lines.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                                 }  # Anonymous code block
 $_,    # The given string as the first line
     .comb[1..*-2]   # The string as a list of chars without the first or last char
                  .&{                      }  # Passed to a function
                     (@_ X~' 'x@_)  # Each character padded with space
                                  Z~[R,] @_   # And zipped with the reverse
    |   # Flattened
                                            ,.flip  # And the reverse of the string
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
LXXb0Qt0_Qy.tym
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=LXXb0Qt0_Qy.tym&input=%22abc%22&debug=0), or verify all the test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=LXXb0Qt0_Qjy.tym&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22ab%22%0A%22abc%22%0A%22Hello%2C%20world%21%22&debug=0) (test suite joins output on newlines for easier verification, as per OP request).

```
LXXb0Qt0_Qy.tymdQ   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
                    Trailing d,Q inferred
L                   Define a function, y(b), as:
  Xb                  Replace in b...
    0                 ... at position 0...
     Q                ... the input string
 X                    Replace in the above...
      t0              ... at position -1 (decrement 0)
        _Q            ... the reversed input string
              mdQ   Split the input string into array of characters
                      (The exact contents of the array don't matter, as long as the array
                       has the same length as the input string and the elements are
                       of length < 2)
             y      Apply the function y (defined above) to the array
                      (For Q="abc", yields ["abc", "b", "cba"]
           .t       Transpose, padding with spaces
                      (For Q="abc", yields ["abc", "b b", "c a"]
          y         Apply y to the above
```

*Edit: OP clarified that a list of lines is acceptable as output, so removed `j` to join on newlines - previous version `LXXb0Qt0_Qjy.tym`*

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>93</s> <s>91</s> <s>87</s> <s>80</s> <s>78</s> <s>77</s> <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...x].map(c=>(w+=z=x[--j])[1]?j?c.padEnd(l-1)+z:w:x,w="",l=j=x.length)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCsMgEADAr7SelOhCrimbnAr9g3gQNWllq5KEKvm8nYn2Zw@3f8qpUvahr9gbzhoAmoGvLdzhzOuAFzatVDRCj2aJi4Ni/TN5TmoUwzXVqcmKjEnCiA0opO18i/5wOR2ZAlDe@MrZKxBleat5J39nQvQ/)

Returns list of lines.

### Explanation

```javascript
x =>                     // Main function
 [...x].map(c =>         // For each character in the input:
  (w += z = x[--j])[1]   //  Check whether this is not the first row (by producing w, the
                         //  reverse of x, character by character, and check if len(w) > 1)
  ?                      //  If so:
   j                     //   Check if this is not the last row
   ? c.padEnd(l - 1) + z //   If so: return the needed row
   : w                   //   If not (i.e. last row): return w, the reverse of x
  : x,                   //  If not (i.e. first row): return x
  w = "",                // Stores the reverse of w
  l = j = x.length       // A variable that stores the length of the string, and a counter
 )                       // Golfing from 78 onwards is tough work.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>80</s> <s>76</s> <s>72</s> 71 bytes

- Saved <s>four</s> <s>eight</s> nine bytes thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni).

```hs
f s=s:m[c:m(' '<$s)++[d]|(c,d)<-zip s$r s]++[r s];m=init.tail;r=reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY6xDsIgFAB/BUmTQqh8QFt2B50ckQGBRiLQhkc1Mf474nKX3HQPDU8XQq0LAgFjlGaMpEf93AFlTFr1JWawdD5@/IagywhUy39NUfjkCy/ahymL7F4ug6tR@ySi3i5k28u15HPihDF8S5jyPQWfHPCFSqzveGgwjac2sA7oveZgD1jVHw)

Comment: Welcome to golfing in Haskell :) `zip(m s)$m$r s` can be `zip<*>r$m s`, though it's still 73 bytes..

Comment: `(' '<$m s)` can be `m(' '<$s)`.

Comment: 71 byte alternative: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY6xDoIwFAB/5dGYACltoiOBzcEBJ8faoepTGkshfUUX/r3W5XK33Wjojc4lOy1ziHA00cjBUkxPoA07ofZSOvSvOAKJg25CJwJ@MBAC9dQqKgrfViWU3Q5rzlXIrTffCdT/0mky1kMPk1nOUC1rvMQweJBQcc6untVZV@@sR8r2rEExc2NNxj3zlNfmBr5zcI@C6fQD "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Also regarding your footer: `sequence.map` is `mapM` and `intercalate"\n"` is `unlines`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>145</strike> 127 bytes

```
func[s][print a: s b: tail s repeat n l:(length? s)- 2[print rejoin[pad first a:
next a l + 1 first b: back b]]print reverse s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy7EgIhFEN7viJS6bgWWtLYWtsyFLBcFGXYnQs@/h5XXQurJGeSMPl2JK@NCKqFW@51MXrkmCusQoFTqDamyTGNZCsyklomyqd63qOsNtjNdabLELMerUeIXN57kek5KRLW2M50OnS2v8IZ89vdiQuhmBYgrZPiy6UUn9z/gwOlNHR4DJz8QrYX)

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>20 19</s> 15 bytes

```
p╡╞▒x_xh *+m+nx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/g0dSFj6bOezRtUkV8RYaClnaudl7F//9KiUnJKalpSgA)

Edited to an improved version of maxb's original 22 byte solution. Zip operator is sadly lacking though the `m`ap operator has a partial implementation.

#### Explanation:

```
p                 Print the original string ["abcd"]
 ╡╞               Remove from the start and end of the string  ["bc"]
   ▒              Convert to a list of chars  [["b","c"]]
    x_x           Reverse, dupe and reverse back again [["c","b"],["b","c"]]
       h          Get length of array without popping  [["c","b"],["b","c"],2]
         *        Create a string with that many spaces [["c","b"],["b","c"],"  "]
          +       Map adding it to every character [["c","b"],["b  ","c  "]]
           m+     Zip add each character of the reversed string [["b  c","c  b"]]
             n    Join with newlines and print
              x   Reverse the original string and implicitly output
```

Comment: You actually beat my MathGolf script that gave inspiration to this challenge! You're right, the zip operator is needed, and mapping for lists is quite rudimental. I'll see how I want that to work.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 11, <s>143</s> <s>142</s> <s>141</s> 140 bytes

```java
s->{for(int l=s.length(),i=l;i>0;)System.out.println(i--<l?i<1?new StringBuffer(s).reverse():s.charAt(l+~i)+" ".repeat(l-2)+s.charAt(i):s);}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bVA9T8MwEN37K45MttpYwEiaVjCx0KUjYnCdS3vFdSL7kgpV4a8HN4lACBZL7935fdxRtzo9Fu@9sToEeNHkLjMAcoy@1AZhc4UAbUUFGLFlT24PQWaR7WbxCayZDGzAQQ59SFeXsvIi/gebB2XR7fkg5IJym9HqNpPbj8B4UlXDqo5abJ2gNF3aNS3v1g7PMFo8NWWJXgSpPLboAwr5EJQ5aP/Iws4/Sc4TSOKwRh2J9F7Ov8cUV2XW9dk1X93sbMw3xRxqnGLJqcnrG2g5NmQMLBK9S4ZuP9j8Jp7R2moB58rb4ib5c4fBYNicTkWubniycMqIEY@K/9xiEuz6Lw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                                // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  for(int l=s.length(),             //  Length of the input-String
      i=l;i>0;)                     //  Loop `i` in the range (length,0]
    System.out.println(             //   Print with trailing newline:
     i--<l?                         //    If it's NOT the first iteration:
                                    //    (and decrease `i` by 1 at the same time)
      i<1?                           //    If it's the last iteration:
       new StringBuffer(s).reverse() //     Print the input reversed
      :                              //    Else:
       s.charAt(l+~i)                //     Print the `l-i-1`'th character,
       +" ".repeat(l-2)              //     appended with length-2 amount of spaces,
       +s.charAt(i):                 //     appended with the `i`'th character
     :                               //   Else (it is the first iteration):
      s);}                           //    Print the input as is
```

Comment: [141 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVA9T8MwEN37K45MttpYwNiQVjCx0KUjYnCdS3vFdSL7kgpV4a8HN4lACBZL7935fdxRtzo9Fu@9sToEeNHkLjMAcoy@1AZhc4UAbUUFGLFlT24PQWaR7WbxCayZDGzAQQ59SFeXsvIi/gebB2XR7fkg5IJym9HqNpPbj8B4UlXDqo5abJ2gNM1zuw5LerhbOzzD6PLUlCV6EaTy2KIPKOQyKHPQ/pGFnX@SnCeQxGGNOhLpvZx/j0nKrOuza8C62dkYcMo59DjFllOV1zfQcqzIGFgkepcM5X6w@U08o7XVAs6Vt8VN8ucQg8GwOd2KXN3wZOGUESMeFf85xiTY9V8) while moving everything to get that `l+~i` which saves the byte.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks. Hadn't thought about reversing the loop. And 1 more byte could be saved with your approach by changing the if-else order a bit (by using `i--<l` instead of `i--==l`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
->s{[s.b,*s.chars.zip(s.reverse!.chars).map{|a|"%s%#{s.size-1}s"%a}[1..-2],s]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchBCoMwEAXQq0RL0BYzYPf2FN2FLEYZMYtCyI@FGnP2tFB4qxf3@VPXqZoHsgXNww20bBxBhw89KMpbIqT555VeHPLJZ6uhLxkEf4gZC1rNxY5E5u4GuFLDnqBW2z03D/XDKglS5@oX)

Comment: Nice solution.

-1 byte: `*s.chars.zip` ->`s.chars.zip`

Comment: I want my function to return a flattened list, so I'm keeping the splat.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you would want that? It doesn't seem to affect the output

Comment: The output of the test is the same because `puts` flattens the list, but the result of the function is a nested array, which is not what I want to return.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for the explination.

Answer (score 3):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 48 bytes

```
00000000: 1525 13cd 0380 3806 ff4d 2377 18f5 3e0a  .%....8..M#w..>.
00000010: ff7b b928 1113 1aff 4105 2805 3e20 ff18  .{.(....A.(.> ..
00000020: f82b 7eff 18e8 131a b720 0176 ff1b 18f7  .+~...... .v....
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc5NagMxDAXgfU/xoBQKASHZmVjJYqDd9xB2xkoXhSGTn0ILvborN80DIy38PvSlfJg/rDX@zw4yhAES9xM4KsPfBmbrCSGmBFEbECtngJ7Io0Rvj59EIz3cBHHDLBWUbVCISIRkM6yFBwTlXg/sX0Td@Kbnrrz4GEF3I3RDQ0Gq3hStDkXJKMmbLKlfJKUfk9xY/dBfQNc@WnutOL/XpcLmpW84HS95qb8)

```
  dec d
  dec h
  inc de
get:
  call $8003
  jr c, got
  rst 38h
  ld c, l
  inc hl
  ld (hl), a
  jr get

got:
  ld a, '\n'
  rst 38h
  ld a, e
  cp c
  jr z, final
  inc de
  ld a, (de)
  rst 38h
  ld b, c
spaces:
  dec b
  jr z, doneb
  ld a, ' '
  rst 38h
  jr spaces
doneb:
  dec hl
  ld a, (hl)
  rst 38h
  jr got

final:
  inc de
reverse:
  ld a, (de)
  or a
  jr nz, cont
  halt
cont:
  rst 38h
  dec de
  jr reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 93 bytes

```powershell
param($s)$s
if(($m=$s.Length-2)-gt0){1..$m|%{$s[$_]+' '*$m+$s[$m-$_+1]}}
-join($s[($m+2)..0])
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($s)$s
if(($m=$s.Length-2)-gt0){1..$m|%{$s[$_]+' '*$m+$s[$m-$_+1]}}
-join($s[($m+2)..0])

}

&$f ab
&$f abc
&$f Hello...
&$f 'Hello, world!'
```

Output:

```powershell
ab
ba
abc
b b
cba
Hello...
e      .
l      .
l      o
o      l
.      l
.      e
...olleH
Hello, world!
e           d
l           l
l           r
o           o
,           w

w           ,
o           o
r           l
l           l
d           e
!dlrow ,olleH
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL(NARS), 59 chars, 118 bytes

```
{y←⊖⍵⋄0=z←¯2+⍴⍵:⊃,¨⍵ y⋄⊃(⊂⍵),({(∊1(z⍴0)1)\⍵}¨¯1↓1↓⍵,¨y),⊂y}
```

test

```
  f←{y←⊖⍵⋄0=z←¯2+⍴⍵:⊃,¨⍵ y⋄⊃(⊂⍵),({(∊1(z⍴0)1)\⍵}¨¯1↓1↓⍵,¨y),⊂y} 
  f '12'
12
21
  f '123'
123
2 2
321
  f '1234'
1234
2  3
3  2
4321
  f 'Hello World!'
Hello World!
e          d
l          l
l          r
o          o
           W
W           
o          o
r          l
l          l
d          e
!dlroW olleH
  f 'Hello, World!'
Hello, World!
e           d
l           l
l           r
o           o
,           W
             
W           ,
o           o
r           l
l           l
d           e
!dlroW ,olleH
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 87 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...s].map((e,i,a,n=s.length)=>i<1?s:i>n-2?a.reverse().join``:e.padEnd(n-1)+a[n+~i])
```

Question Title is **Be there, for the Square** but all answers print a **Rectangle**
So here's the one printing square:

```
s=>[...s].map((e,i,a,n=s.length)=>i<1?a.join` `:i>n-2?a.reverse().join` `:e.padEnd(2*n-2)+a[n+~i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDoIwEADQX1GnNpRLcCQWJkcnR0LChR54pF4JB4z@en1vwRN13HjdS0mB8uSz@qYDAO3hi6sx5NihE68QSeb9Y33Dj6rVmhsp7y3CRidtSsbCkliGoSZYMTwlGCkrW2AnxY97m8ckmiJBTLOZzO2N8djJXV6HBL7erM1/)

Comment: `s[n+~i]` saves 1 byte over `n-i-1`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>92</s> 85 bytes

Early morning golf on the bus. Not happy with it; there's definitely a shorter way :\

```
s=>s+`
`+(g=r=>--x?s[l-x].padEnd(l)+s[--y]+`
`+g(r+s[y]):r+s[0])(s[l=x=y=s.length-1])
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HcrBCgIhEIDhe2/RTbGRugaznYJ9h0VQVteKQRdnKX162zr9/PC93NvxXJ7rBin70BfsjAMre7BKRCw4ANQbTwTV6NX5e/KCpOIJoJm/iqLs24y8/no2UuwaKzZkTSHF7QEXI/ucE2cKmnIUi7BjIMqnTy7kj1bK/gU)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 28 bytes

*Takes the input as an array of characters*

```
íUz2)£Y©Y<UÊÉ?XqSpUÊ-2:UqÃow
```

---

```
íUz2)£Y©Y<UÊÉ?XqSpUÊ-2:UqÃow    Full program. Implicity input U
                                ["a", "b", "c"]
 Uz2)                           Duplicate and rotate 180°
                                ["a", "b", "c"], ["c", "b", "a"]
í                               Pair each item at the same index
                                [["a","c"],["b","b"], ["c","a"]]
     £                          Map
      Y©Y<                      If index is positive and less than
          UÊÉ?                  Length - 1
              Xq                Join with...
                SpUÊ-2          Space repeated (U length - 2) times
                                [["a","c"],"b b", ["c","a"]]
                      :Uq       Else return joined input
                                ["abc","b b", "abc"]
                         Ãow    Map last item and reverse
                                ["abc","b b", "cba"]
                                Implicity output array joined with new lines
                                "abc
                                 b b
                                 cba"
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=7VV6MimjWalZPFXKyT9YcVNwVcotMjpVccNvdw==&input=WyJIIiwiZSIsImwiLCJsIiwibyIsIiAiLCJXIiwibyIsInIiLCJsIiwiZCIsIiEiXSAtUgoK)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
W;ḊW€$O‘z0ṚUoƊo33’ỌY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/c@uGOrvBHTWtU/B81zKgyeLhzVmj@sa58Y@NHDTMf7u6J/P//vwdQab6OQnh@UU6KIgA)

Assuming that unprintables can also be in the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
▄▀τƒ○≡ë'▲.
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=dcdfe79f09f089271e2e&i=%22Hello,+world%21%22&a=1)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
{       start a block to repeat
  Mr    rotate matrix counter-clockwise
  0     actually just a literal 0
  x     retrieve "string" from x register, initially the input string
  rX    reverse, and write it back to register
  &     assign reversed "string" to 0 index of matrix (first row)
}4*     exectue block 4 times
m       output matrix as line-separated rows
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B+++%09start+a+block+to+repeat%0A++Mr%09rotate+matrix+counter-clockwise%0A++0+%09actually+just+a+literal+0%0A++x+%09retrieve+%22string%22+from+x+register,+initially+the+input+string%0A++rX%09reverse,+and+write+it+back+to+register%0A++%26+%09assign+reversed+%22string%22+to+0+index+of+matrix+%28first+row%29%0A%7D4*+%09exectue+block+4+times%0Am+++%09output+matrix+as+line-separated+rows&i=%22Hello,+world%21%22&a=1)

Comment: Would `í,ñl♠τ¢∞█` be fine for 9, outputting as a list of lines?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder:  I'm not sure, but if it is, this 8 byte solution would also work.  Ç¢å╒Γ8Q#  Personally, I don't really like it.  For languages that don't have real functions I think the output should be formatted correctly on standard output, so there's nothing left to interpretation about what the internal state of different languages mean.  But on the other hand, I'm in favor of smaller programs!

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>100</s> <s>103</s> 102 bytes

- Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat); golfing an alternative solution.

```c
o,O;v(char*_){for(O=puts(_,o=0)-2;O-++o;)printf("%c%*c\n",_[o],O,_[O-o]);for(o=O;~o;putchar(_[o--]));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BDoIwEER/RZuQ7EKbiNcNd2/9ACEEV1ESYElFPBD99dpy9TTJZN4bNndm70VbWoAfjUtrXFtxYIvpNT@h1lIc0BzJmiwTwsl149yCSjhJuRyVrs9SaRvCGqmQIiqFpa9Q4KMQwsKYCpE@fmi6EXBdQDUXhbQ9qGBB2ir@68r8dOt70bu3uP66V1keNT8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>19</s>  18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to Erik the Outgolfer (managing to use another repeat, `⁺`, to inline my helper Link)

```
WẋL¬o1¦³ṚUƊ⁺ZƊ⁺o⁶Y
```

A full program.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/84a5un0Nr8g0PLTu0@eHOWaHHuh417ooCk/mPGrdF/v//X8kDqDZfRyE8vygnRVEJAA)**

#### How?

```
WẋL¬o1¦³ṚUƊ⁺ZƊ⁺o⁶Y - Main Link: list of characters s
W                  - wrap s in a list
  L                - length of s
 ẋ                 - repeat (yielding a length(s) list of copies of s)
   ¬               - logical NOT (makes every element a zero - giving us a square of zeros)
             Ɗ     - last three links as a monad (say F(x)):
          Ɗ        -   last three links as a monad (say G(x)):
      ¦            -     sparse application...
     1             -       ...to indices: [1]
    o  ³           -       ...do: logical OR with the input (s)
                   -              (replaces the first list with the input)
        Ṛ          -     reverse               }
         U         -     upend (reverse each)  } (turn whole thing 180 degrees)
           ⁺       -   repeat previous link (i.e. G(that result))
            Z      -   transpose
              ⁺    - repeat previous link (i.e. F(that result))
               o⁶  - logical OR with a space character (replace all remaining zeros with spaces)
                 Y - join with newlines
                   - implicitly print
```

---

My 19 byters...

```
;⁶ɓJ»þ`n\«\aƊUṚ»ƊịY
```

[Try this one](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9qZWxsef//O@KBtsmTSsK7w75gblzCq1xhxopV4bmawrvGiuG7i1n///8iSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkISI), which works by building a table of indices filled with zeros and then indexing into the input with an extra space (in order to relace the 0s with spaces)

...and the one Erik improved to 18 for me:

```
o1¦³ṚU
WẋL¬ÇÇZƊ⁺o⁶Y
```

[Try this one](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9qZWxsef//bzHCpsKz4bmaVQpX4bqLTMKsw4fDh1rGiuKBum/igbZZ////IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi).

Comment: ["Another 19"?](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/84a5un0Nr8g0PLTu0@eHOWaHHuh417ooCk/mPGrdF/v//X8kDqDZfRyE8vygnRVEJAA)

Comment: Oh, thanks Erik - I can't remember quite what I tried for that  double repeat, but whatever it was it was wrong!

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>113</s> 102 bytes

```r
function(s,N=nchar(s),m=matrix(" ",N,N)){m[1,]=m[,1]=el(strsplit(s,""))
write(pmax(m,rev(m)),1,N,,"")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYuxCsIwEED3fkW86Q7OobvZnbo6lA4xJhjIteUStSB@e6yD04P3eNqiOR1bfMy@pmXGwoOd/d0pFmKx4qqmDcEADzwQvWXsebIycj/ZkLFULWtOdf8AiLqXphpwFbehsIYnChH3@/vLnxYRziHnhc1l0Xw7AHW7ctc/PVD7Ag)

*Thanks to [JayCe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80010/jayce) for saving 6 bytes!*

Writes the string to the first row and column of the array. So long as the string contains only characters with ASCII codepoints greater or equal than 32 (space), which seems allowable by "alphanumeric characters", then the parallel maximum of the matrix and its reverse yields the appropriate matrix, which is then printed out by `write`.

Comment: [111 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYuxCsIwEEB3v6J2uoNziF1EzK5LpopD6RBbg4HkAukVBPHbY3R5PB68XFxz2hW38iQ@MSxkNE9Pm2FBijpayf4F3Z4MGcR3HBSNOg6kfjRHReYvVHXUq7hDny4sdd5MVsCz9OlaK@S75xkiqQ4RP8VBe36EkKi5pRzmbYvlCw) using `intToUtf8` and `cat`

Comment: actually your solution can be made [107 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYy7CgIxEEV7vyJONQNjkVZMb5XWYtliWRMM5CGTLArit8eszeFwuFzpXl1O3W95baFkrGxNXh@LYCVOJi1NwhtBAVu2RJ80aZ5NmljvtGfN9i88dDYuYm1SnzG08QRAdHhJaA4TjyHv5ds9wtXFWFjdisT7Eaj/AA) easily :)

Comment: @JayCe oh duh! I mostly just played with the indices until they were right and didn't even think to golf them! I even managed to find a few more :-)

Comment: `pmax` is a really good trick. I've been trying to use a vector like [this](https://tio.run/##NYu7DsIwDEX3fkXxZCMzlLGiO1PWDhVIJaSiUtxGTnhIiG8PYWC6R@foap7qwy5P98WmeV0wsukWexsVI7F06gJCDWzOe6K3DE1rTp0Mpm22BZzHmDQGP6dyBCCqnjonh0HGFwqre6AQccOGf/mTJ4Sj837lul/VXzdAVVHj5b8WKH8B) but I am not managing to save bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 109 bytes

```java
s->{int l=s.length,i=0;var r=new char[l][l--];for(char c:s)r[i][0]=r[0][i]=r[l-i][l]=r[l][l-i++]=c;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU@xbsIwEN3zFVeWJiWx6JpgqqpS1aVTx8iDMQmYGjs6OyCE8u2pHSDpgiz5zvfePb@350ee7Te/vTw0Bh3s/Zu0TipSt1o4aTR5KSKhuLXwzaW@RABNu1ZSgHXc@XI0cgMHD8U/DqXelgw4bm0CgQrweZNZih3HkqXXUrIV1EB7m60uUjtQ1BJV6a3bpZIuiiNHQKqrEwx0xUqVZayoDcZhACK3CZaSlQtG0V@@9VVlfqKGLizI@ZxRUWDlWtSARdcXg6PRpquss0BvRgFmfD1Lp15Mj69KKZPCyaDaPM2GaXcVC5aC26CVXxWTUXCI4T@oCW8adY4DTJz58BHeEfk5TpLiRr1H87ZsDjhpTJBPDfY/4KOcrasOxLSOND6UiwUs4RXe4NmfHMQo7/1Gj5aUjkfenfWYExhd1PV/)

Returning a 2D array containing the characters to print. The inner of the array is filled with `\0` instead of spaces because no rules said spaces have to be used.

Answer (score 1):

**[C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), <strike>232</strike>  231 bytes**

Edit: included the include statements in byte count, removed all white spaces, and removed include string.h, Thanks [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BisMwDETv/QpBD7XbJJCz3R76G6UHr6N1BImdWk4JlH671y4LC3sRYp5mRnZZWmdt3pO30zogaAqcIpr5svvTzORCpDTOl7wyeQfezMiLsQicBjUb8oJ8AtvY0UQ4Ho18lZR6yWdz6@@q0u3M3YTepVHItm9I9FLZsCatWWv0w6S@QxSK9KZOJ5K/6Eb3Mj9hYiu2Axxklbe2go8t4hMjo@DuC115RTbcFSDk//x3zleENGJEKF11A36sJmJOyAlc@AE)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;main(int c,char **a){string s=a[1];int x=s.length()-1,i(1);cout<<s<<endl;for(;i<x;++i)cout<<s[i]<<string(x-1,' ')<<s[x-i]<<endl;reverse(s.begin(),s.end());cout<<s<<endl;}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Indentation and most newlines are not necessary for C++, you can remove them to save bytes.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can save a lot of bytes by eliminating whitespace. You should be able to save more byte by submitting a function instead of a full program. However, you do have to add `#include<iostream>` and `#include<algorithm>` to your byte count. `#include<string.h>` doesn't seem to be required.

Comment: Just a few more (and correct TIO link): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BasQwDETv/QpDD2vvJoGc7e2hv7HsQXVUR5DYqaWUQOm3u/ZSeuhFiHmaGflt64P3pTxT9Ms@oaPEkhHWl6c/CZaQMslctZ0pBhVhRd7Ao2KZ7AoUNUVRvvMz5PMZzFfNaId8hdt4tw0eVx4WjEFmbfqxIz0a69MuzrFzGKfFvqesLbnDXi5kftGN7nU@wvRRbSd1Mk0@@gYetoyfmBk1D28Y6iem46ECbf7nf5fyikpmzKhqV9sUf@yQsQiyqJB@AA "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: [222 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY7LCoMwFET3/Qqhm8QX2C4T@yPiIo238YImkhuLUPrtaSxS6GYWZ4bD6GWpjNYxntHqaR1AoqPgQc230w@pyTiPYUxsJbQms2oGWpSGjMIgZoWWoQ0ZlnpUPs8VfyXHPqRWddg2vdjrraV6AmvCyHjViIfzTLs1SElSgh0mgXIT/EAd9im/FrZVTXm98J1uFRZFf@w9PMETMKrvYNIHXlKdCsa5@Be/Y4wBKGTGfQA "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: You can most likely drop the last `<<endl`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 207 Bytes

```
$k=str_pad('',($L=mb_strlen($s=$argv[1]))-2,' ');$p=[];for($i=1;$i<=$L;$i++){$p[]=($j=mb_substr($s,$L-$i,1));if($i==1)$b=$s;elseif($i==$L)$b=implode('',$p);else$b=mb_substr($s,$i-1,1).$k.$j;echo$b.PHP_EOL;}
```

Not quite a creative entry, but it supports UTF-8 at least...

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>34, 31</strike> 30 bytes

```
,(1|:@|.(2+#){.|.,:])@}.@}:,|.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F9Hw7DGyqFGT8NIW1mzWq9GT8cqVtOhVs@h1kqnRu@/JpeSnoJ6mq2euoKOQq2VQloxF1dqcka@QpqCemKSOoStrqurq44knIxV3CM1JydfR6E8vygnRVGd6z8A)

### Explanation:

```
 ,(1|:@|.(2+#){.|.,:])@}.@}:,|. 
                            ,   - append
                             |. - the reversed input to
  (                  )@}.@}:    - the input with the first and the last chars dropped and
                |.              - its reverse
                  ,.            - laminated to
                    ]           - the trimmed input (results in a matrix 2 x length )
              {.                - take as many rows (pad with empty lines)
         (2+#)                  - as is length of the input (2+length of the trimmed input)
       |.                       - rotate
   1                            - one position to the top
    |:@                         - and transpose
 '                              - prepend with the input
```

Comment: (1j1&#"1,(1|."1(3++:@#){."1|.,.])@}.@}:,1j1&#"1@|.) prints in squared format

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 78 bytes

```
(.+).
$1¶$&
O$^r`.\G

+`^(.*)(.)(¶(.*).)
$1¶$2$4$3
^¶

T`p` `(?<=.¶.).*(?=.¶.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fQ09bU49LxfDQNhU1Ln@VuKIEvRh3Li7thDgNPS1NDT1NjUPbQCw9TYgiIxUTFWOuuEPbuLhCEgoSFBI07G1s9Q5t09PU09Kwh7D@//dIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVEEAA) Handliy beating my [previous attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133762/17602). Explanation:

```
(.+).
$1¶$&
```

Duplicate all but one character.

```
O$^r`.\G
```

Reverse the original.

```
+`^(.*)(.)(¶(.*).)
$1¶$2$4$3
```

Move characters from the duplicate to the original one at a time, creating a filled square.

```
^¶
```

Delete the blank line now that the duplicate has been processed.

```
T`p` `(?<=.¶.).*(?=.¶.)
```

Change all inner characters to spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 29 bytes

```apl
⊢⍪⌽⍪⍨1⌽⊢∘≢↑⍤1(↑⌽⍪¨⊢)∘(1↓¯1↓⊢)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEddix71rnrUsxdE9q4wBLGAQh0zHnUuetQ28VHvEkMNEA1WcGgFUE4TKKlh@Kht8qH1IBIkAjRKQT0xSZ1LXUGdC8xMhrM9UnNy8nUUyvOLclIU1QE)

Uses the same algorithm as my J solution.

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 179 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ varchar(99),@n INT=2SELECT @=v FROM i PRINT @
a:PRINT SUBSTRING(@,@n,1)+SPACE(LEN(@)-2)+SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@),@n,1)SET @n+=1IF @n<len(@)GOTO a
IF LEN(@)>2PRINT REVERSE(@)
```

Input is taken via pre-existing table **i** with varchar field **v**, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>19</s> 18 bytes

Returns an array of lines.

```
¬íU¬w)mq¢ç)hJUw)hU
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rO1VrHcpbXGi5yloSlV3KWhV&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEiCi1S)

Saved a byte thanks to Oliver.

Comment: You can replace `U¤` with `¢`

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks, @Oliver; I'd forgotten about `¢`, can't remember the last time I used it.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA (Excel), 86 bytes

Using Immediate Window and Cell `[a1]` as input.

```
a=[a1]:b=StrReverse(a):c=Len(a):?a:For i=2To c-1:?Mid(a,i,1)Spc(c-2)Mid(b,i,1):Next:?b
```

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 51 bytes

```
Ù:se ri
y$2o"mm2kÓ./&ò
dk2GddG:&&
dd'mdk$ëp'mdG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BMq@JUhaJMrkoVo3whJencXKPsw5P19NUOb@JKyTZyT0lxt1JT40pJEVPPTclWETu8ugDIcP//3yM1JydfITy/KCcFAA)

```
00000000: d93a 7365 2072 690a 7924 326f 1222 1b6d  .:se ri.y$2o.".m
00000010: 6d32 6bd3 2e2f 26f2 0a64 6b32 4764 6447  m2k../&..dk2GddG
00000020: 3a26 260a 6464 1627 6d64 6b24 16eb 7027  :&&.dd.'mdk$..p'
00000030: 6d64 47                                  mdG
```

```
Ù                                Duplicate line
 :se ri                          Enable reverse input.
y$                               Copy one line without line-break
  2o<C-r>"<Esc>                  With reverse input enabled, insert copied string in a new line twice
               mm                Set a mark in the last line
                 2kÓ./&ò         Go to second line, add a line break between each character
                                 This created the left edge of the square
dk2Gdd                           Delete first and last character of left edge
      G:&&                       Go to last line, repeat last substitution; this creates the right edge
dd                               Delete the final empty line that was just created
  <C-v>'md                       The right edge is currently below the square; delete it there
          k$<C-v>ëp              And put it in the right place
                   'mdG          Finally, remove excess new lines
```